# Will local temp tables be dropped if the stored procedure errors out due to exception if Drop is not explicitly mentioned

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

As per the microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables),

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
> automatically when the stored procedure is finished

Will the local temp tables still be dropped automatically if the stored procedure fails due to exception?

If no, should it be considered mandatory to always Drop local temp tables for failure cases?

Comment: Anyway, cleaning up yourself is always a good practice

Comment: If the procedure fails then it's also finished. So yes, the temp tables are dropped.  Dropping temp tables in a stored  procedure is more done to free some temp space during a long running heavy procedure.

Answer (score 1):

They get dropped anyway.

Here's a simplified test to demonstrate.

But no one will complain if you explicitly drop them when they aren't needed anymore in the stored procedure.  Probably.

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE procTest
> @Input INT
> AS 
> DECLARE @Output AS DECIMAL(18,2)
> BEGIN
>   CREATE TABLE #Tmp (
>    Col INT
>   );
>   INSERT INTO #Tmp (Col) VALUES (42);
>   
>   SELECT @Output = (SELECT TOP 1 1.0*Col/@Input FROM #Tmp);
>   
>   -- DROP TABLE #Tmp;
>   RETURN @Output;
> END;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE   @return_value int
> EXEC  @return_value = procTest @Input = 2;
> SELECT @return_value as return_value;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | return_value |
> | -----------: |
> |           21 |
> ```

> ```
> select * from #Tmp;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 208 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> Invalid object name '#Tmp'.
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE   @return_value int
> EXEC  @return_value = procTest @Input = 0;
> SELECT @return_value as return_value;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 8134 Level 16 State 1 Line 11
> Divide by zero error encountered.
> Msg 282 Level 0 State 1 Line 14
> The 'procTest' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.
> ```

> ```
> select * from #Tmp;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 208 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> Invalid object name '#Tmp'.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf602560c323ed674a35e17224ba6b8d)*